# How to stop Outlook from asking for Profile in RemoteApp

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, remoteapp

We are running our ERP software as a RemoteApp in Remote Desktop.  The Server is 2008r2sp1 with latest updates as of 06-23-2016.  The ERP software calls Outlook 2010sp2 in order to send POs as email.  No matter what I've tried, every time Outlook starts from our ERP software I get the "Choose profile" dialog.

1. I've tried Options->Set as Default Profile in the "Choose Profile" dialog.  The dialog still appears every time.
2. I've tried logging in as the user and setting "Always use this profile" in Control Panel -> Mail.  (It was already set that way)
3. I've tried setting HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Client\Options\PickLogonProfile to 0 (it was already set to zero).
4. If I start Outlook after logging into the server normally through Remote Desktop I do not get the "Choose Profile" dialog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is Outlook also running as a RemoteApp, or is it installed locally on the client machines?

Comment: Outlook is installed on the remote Server, but is not published as a RemoteApp.

Comment: If it's not installed as a RemoteApp, then I'm confused as to how you're seeing the "Choose profile" dialog...?   You are running the ERP RemoteApp from your workstation correct?  Does your workstation also have Outlook installed?  When you say you made those Outlook registry adjustments, where did you make them? On your workstation, or on the server hosting the RemoteApp?  Was the version of Outlook installed on the server a Volume Licence version (vs. Retail, or OEM)?

Comment: The ERP software, the published remoteapp, installed on the remote server, is calling Outlook, also installed on the remote server, from it's programming.  I know it's working this way because I have O2016 installed on my workstation, and the ERP software is starting O2010 (it only supports <=O2010).  I made the registry adjustments on the server while logged in as the testing user.  The version installed on the server is part of my SA, Open Value.  I would assume that's volume licensing.